# Dijkstra Algorithm property

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory, dijkstra

```
Dijkstra(G,w,s) {
  ISS(G,s);
  let S be an empty set
  let Q be a priority queue, initialized with V[G]
  while Q is not Empty:
       u<-extractMin(Q);
       add u to S
       for each vertex v neighbor of u
             Relax(u,v,w);
}
```

my question is, why is it important to choose the MINIMUM d[v] of all v in Q in every step of the algorithm in the while loop, whats gonna heppen if we dont choose the minimum?

i mean from the way i see it, all edges (u,v) are gonna get relaxed in a breadth first order(means that if -  s->u->v and (s,v) not in E then (s,u) would get relaxed before (u,v)), 
so why is it important to choose the minimal d[v] every time?

assume there exists a function extractMaxFiniteD(Q) that returns vertex v such that it has max d[v] that is finite in Q

lets assume we change that line to u<-extractMaxFiniteD(Q); can any one draw me a graph in which the modified alg would fail - or even better - what property of shortest path would get violeted?

I know this question might be pretty hard and abstract, but it would be great if some1 could help me with that.

Comment: Did you actually try it on ANY graph? The probability that using Max will yield incorrect results is VERY high!

Comment: im less intrested in a specific graph, i want to understand what property are we trying to preserve by choosing the minimal every step.

Comment: If you do that on almost ANY graph, going step by step and seeing the intermediate results, you'll understand the purpose of min

Comment: choosing infinity is not legit ovcourse,lets assume extractMaxFiniteD returns vertex v such that it has max d[v] that is finite in Q, is it still that trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example:

nodes: a,b,c
edges (and weights): (a,b,1) (a,c,10) (b,c,1)

try your algorithm on this. you'll find that the least cost path to c is 10 when its obviously 2.

when you remove a node from Q you don't relax it ever again, if you remove a node with maximal cost  then you don't consider less expesive ways to reach that node.

if you don't want to select the minimal node from Q then you can't remove it from Q either, you must keep it in the set so it can be relaxed in future iterations. that's basically what the [bellman-ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm does.

Answer (score 7):

The main idea behing Dijkstra's algorithm is: when you take a vertex out of `Q`, this vertex is good. You won't have to relax it in the fututre.

If you take a random element from `Q`, this condition doesn't hold - once you took a vertex `v` out of `Q`, it is not guaranteed the `d[v]` is indeed the shortest path to `v`.

If you take the minimal - it is guaranteed, since if `v` is minimal in `Q`, then for each `u` in `Q`, `d[u] >= d[v]`, thus no matter which relexations you do next - you cannot improve `d[v]`